# Need to modify CSS to megamenu to make it work

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, sharepoint

I work on a SharePoint project and I was asked to create a global navigation that got its data from a SharePoint list. I was able to successfully implement this with no problem.  I created a mock-up that can be found [here](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/0a683c74eb14b5a8122509d803f5f9d3).

```js
let myMockListData = [
 {
  URL: "/siteA.aspx",
  URLNAME: "Home",
    dropDown: "no",
    id: "home"
 },  
 {
  URL: "/siteA.aspx",
  URLNAME: "Site A",
    dropDown: "yes",
    id: "SiteA"
 },
 {
  URL: "/siteB.aspx",
  URLNAME: "Site B",
    dropDown: "no",
    id: "siteB"
 },
 {
  URL: "/siteC.aspx",
  URLNAME: "Site C",
    dropDown: "yes",
    id: "SiteC"
 },
 { URL: "/siteD.aspx", URLNAME: "Site D", dropDown: "no", id: "siteD" },
 { URL: "/siteE.aspx", URLNAME: "Site E", dropDown: "no", id: "siteE" }
];

var subList = [
  {subURL: "/site/a", id:"SiteA", URLNAME: "Site A"},
  {subURL: "/site/c", id:"SiteC", URLNAME: "Site C"},
  {subURL: "/site/a", id:"SiteA", URLNAME: "Site A"},
  {subURL: "/site/a", id:"SiteA", URLNAME: "Site A"},
  {subURL: "/site/c", id:"SiteC", URLNAME: "Site C"},
  {subURL: "/site/a", id:"SiteA", URLNAME: "Site A"},
  {subURL: "/site/c", id:"SiteC", URLNAME: "Site C"}
]

createNavigation(myMockListData);

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

function createNavigation(navData){ 
  var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  for (var x=0; x<navData.length; x++){
    
    if (navData[x].dropDown === "no"){
            var aLink = _createEl("a");
       var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(navData[x].URLNAME);
        aLink.href=navData[x].URL;
        aLink.appendChild(aTextNode);
        topNav.appendChild(aLink);
    }else{
                var buildSubNavigation;
          
          buildSubNavigation = buildSubNavBar(navData[x].id);
          console.log(buildSubNavigation)
          topNav.appendChild(buildSubNavigation)
    }
  }
}

function buildSubNavBar(subNavID){
  console.log(subNavID)
  //create div and add dropdown class
    var ddDiv = _createEl("div");
    ddDiv.classList.add("dropdown");
  //create button and add text
    var btn = _createEl("button");
  btn.classList.add("dropbtn")
    var btnText = document.createTextNode(subNavID);
  //append the text to the button
    btn.appendChild(btnText);
  //append the button to the div
    ddDiv.appendChild(btn);
  //create i tag and add "fa fa-caret-down" classes
    var itag = _createEl("i");
        itag.classList.add("fa")
        itag.classList.add("fa-caret-down")
   btn.appendChild(itag)
   ddDiv.appendChild(btn)
  
  var ddContent = _createEl("div");
      ddContent.classList.add("dropdown-content")
    for (var i=0; i<subList.length; i++){
      if (subList[i].id === subNavID){
          var li = _createEl("li");
          var a = _createEl("a");
          var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(subList[i].URLNAME);
        
          a.href = subList[i].subURL;
          a.appendChild(aTextNode);
          ddContent.appendChild(a)
     //li.appendChild(aTextNode);      
       } 
    }
  
  ddDiv.appendChild(ddContent)
  return ddDiv;
}

function _createEl(el){
  return document.createElement(el);
}











/*
//Function call to dynamically build navigation based on datasource
buildNavBar(myMockListData);

//shortcut for document.createElement()
function _crE(el){
  return document.createElement(el);
}

function buildSubNavBar(subNavID){
    var ul = _crE("ul");
    ul.classList.add("dropdown-menu");
  
    for (var i=0; i<subList.length; i++){
      if (subList[i].id === subNavID){
          var li = _crE("li");
          var a = _crE("a");
          var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(subList[i].URLNAME);
        
          a.href = subList[i].subURL;
          a.appendChild(aTextNode);
          li.appendChild(a)
     //li.appendChild(aTextNode);
          ul.appendChild(li);        
       }
    }
 
  return ul;
}

function buildNavBar(navData){
  
  for (var x=0; x<navData.length; x++){
      var li = _crE("li");
    
      if(navData[x].URLNAME == "Home")
        li.classList.add("active");
    
        var buildSubNavigation="";

        if(navData[x].dropDown === "yes"){
          li.setAttribute("id", navData[x].id)
          buildSubNavigation = buildSubNavBar(navData[x].id);
          console.log(buildSubNavigation)
          li.appendChild(buildSubNavigation)
        }

      var li_a = _crE("a");  
      if (navData[x].dropDown == "no"){
        li_a.href = navData[x].URL;
      } else {
        li_a.href = navData[x].URL;
        li_a.classList.add("dropdown-toggle");
        li_a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown")
        
        var newSpan = _crE("span");
            newSpan.classList.add("caret")
        li_a.appendChild(newSpan);
      }   
         //create the textnode(urlname) from list and complete link creation
     var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(navData[x].URLNAME);
     li_a.appendChild(aTextNode);
    
       li.appendChild(li_a);
      var idNav = document.getElementById("test")
  idNav.appendChild(li)
  }
}
*/

/*


/* function buildNavBar(navData){
    //Get a reference to the parent of where the nav will go
    var parentDiv = document.querySelector("#subNav");      
    var mainUl = document.getElementById("s4-titlerow");
    
    //Loop through the data from the REST API call to the list cointaining navigation information
    for (var x=0; x<navData.length; ++x){
     console.log(navData);
     
     //Create a span and anchor for each navigation link
     var navspan = document.createElement("span");
     var navA = document.createElement("a");
     
     //add href attribute set to url from list
     navA.href = navData[x].URL;
     
     //create the textnode(urlname) from list and complete link creation
     var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(navData[x].URLNAME);
     navA.appendChild(aTextNode);
    
     //append the link to the span
     navspan.appendChild(navA);
     
     //append nav to div
     parentDiv.appendChild(navspan);
    }
   }*/
```

```css
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

w3schools had a static version and I used dom manipulation to make it dynamic. I'm using an array of objects to mimic a SharePoint list.

Here's the **problem** I'm having - one of the menu-items needed to be a mega-menu.  I also mimicked the code found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_mega_menu_responsive) to create the mega-menu.  When **Directorate** is hovered over, the mega-menu will appear.  I merged the CSS of the Navigation with the CSS of the mega-menu and I think that's where I'm having the issue.  I believe the problem I'm having is found in this piece of code below when I'm add the class to the elements as I'm looping through the menu-items from the array.  When I loop, I need to give the mega-menu item a different class name 'Mdropdown' and 'Mdropbtn'

```
function createNavigation(navData) {
var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
for (var x = 0; x < navData.length; x++) {
    if (navData[x].dropDown === "no") {
        var aLink = _createEl("a");
        var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(navData[x].URLNAME);
        aLink.href = navData[x].URL;
        aLink.appendChild(aTextNode);
        topNav.appendChild(aLink);
    } else if (navData[x].dropDown === "yes") {
        var buildSubNavigation;
        buildSubNavigation = buildSubNavBar(navData[x].id);
        topNav.appendChild(buildSubNavigation);
    } else {
        //build megamenu
        var buildSubNavigation;
        buildDirectorateNav = buildDirectorateMegaMenu(navData[x].id);
    }
}
}
function buildSubNavBar(subNavID, isDirectorate) {
//create div and add dropdown class
var ddDiv = _createEl("div");
ddDiv.classList.add("dropdown");   <------- if classname is prefixed with 'M', it works partially
//create button and add text
var btn = _createEl("button");
btn.classList.add("dropbtn");      <------- if classname is prefixed with 'M', it works partially
var btnText = document.createTextNode(subNavID);
//append the text to the button
btn.appendChild(btnText);
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/f45392906c2bdd522e2aceb9ad9c4805?editors=0110) for a more clearer picture.  If you change line 115 to `ddDiv.classList.add("Mdropdown");`  and line 118 to `btn.classList.add("Mdropbtn");`, you will see that the mega-menu will work when you hover over **Directorate** but that **SiteA** and **SiteC** will stop working.

```js
//https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_mega_menu.asp
let myMockListData = [
 {
  URL: "/siteA.aspx",
  URLNAME: "Home",
  dropDown: "no",
  id: "home"
 },
 {
  URL: "/siteA.aspx",
  URLNAME: "Site A",
  dropDown: "yes",
  id: "SiteA"
 },
 {
  URL: "/siteB.aspx",
  URLNAME: "Site B",
  dropDown: "no",
  id: "siteB"
 },
 {
  URL: "/siteC.aspx",
  URLNAME: "Site C",
  dropDown: "yes",
  id: "SiteC"
 },
 { URL: "/siteD.aspx", URLNAME: "Site D", dropDown: "no", id: "siteD" },
 { URL: "/siteE.aspx", URLNAME: "Site E", dropDown: "no", id: "siteE" },
 {
  URL: "/siteE.aspx",
  URLNAME: "Directorate",
  dropDown: "directorate",
  id: "Directorate"
 }
];

var subList = [
 { subURL: "/site/a", id: "SiteA", URLNAME: "Site A" },
 { subURL: "/site/c", id: "SiteC", URLNAME: "Site C" },
 { subURL: "/site/a", id: "SiteA", URLNAME: "Site A" },
 { subURL: "/site/a", id: "SiteA", URLNAME: "Site A" },
 { subURL: "/site/c", id: "SiteC", URLNAME: "Site C" },
 { subURL: "/site/a", id: "SiteA", URLNAME: "Site A" },
 { subURL: "/site/c", id: "SiteC", URLNAME: "Site C" }
];

var megaMenuCategory = [
 { category: "BL", url: "www.gmail.com" },
 { category: "DT", url: "www.gmail.com" },
 { category: "HR", url: "www.gmail.com" },
 { category: "IT", url: "www.gmail.com" },
 { category: "NE", url: "www.gmail.com" },
 { category: "SD", url: "www.gmail.com" },
 { category: "SI", url: "www.gmail.com" },
 { category: "OB", url: "www.gmail.com" }
];

var categoryMenu = [
 { category: "BL", menuItem: "BL-AQ", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "BL", menuItem: "BL-AC", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "BL", menuItem: "BL-EL", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "DT", menuItem: "DT-BT", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "DT", menuItem: "DT-SE", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "DT", menuItem: "DT-PI", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "HR", menuItem: "Human Resources", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "IT", menuItem: "IT-IO", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "IT", menuItem: "IT-CS", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "SD", menuItem: "SD-CB", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "SD", menuItem: "SD-CX", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" },
 { category: "SD", menuItem: "SD-EC", menuUrl: "wwww.gmail.com" }
];

createNavigation(myMockListData);

function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
 if (x.className === "topnav") {
  x.className += " responsive";
 } else {
  x.className = "topnav";
 }
}

function createNavigation(navData) {
 var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
 for (var x = 0; x < navData.length; x++) {
  if (navData[x].dropDown === "no") {
   var aLink = _createEl("a");
   var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(navData[x].URLNAME);
   aLink.href = navData[x].URL;
   aLink.appendChild(aTextNode);
   topNav.appendChild(aLink);
  } else if (navData[x].dropDown === "yes") {
   var buildSubNavigation;
   buildSubNavigation = buildSubNavBar(navData[x].id);
   topNav.appendChild(buildSubNavigation);
  } else {
   //build megamenu
   var buildSubNavigation;
   buildDirectorateNav = buildDirectorateMegaMenu(navData[x].id);
  }
 }
}

function buildDirectorateMegaMenu(navDataID) {
 var buildNav;
 var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
 buildNav = buildSubNavBar(navDataID, "directorate");  //Build mega menu and attach in buildSubNavBar()
 topNav.appendChild(buildNav);
}

function buildSubNavBar(subNavID, isDirectorate) {
 //create div and add dropdown class
 var ddDiv = _createEl("div");
 ddDiv.classList.add("dropdown");
 //create button and add text
 var btn = _createEl("button");
 btn.classList.add("dropbtn");
 var btnText = document.createTextNode(subNavID);
 //append the text to the button
 btn.appendChild(btnText);
  
 //create i tag and add "fa fa-caret-down" classes
 var itag = _createEl("i");
 itag.classList.add("fa");
 itag.classList.add("fa-caret-down");
 btn.appendChild(itag);
 ddDiv.appendChild(btn);

 var ddContent = _createEl("div");
 ddContent.classList.add("dropdown-content");
 for (var i = 0; i < subList.length; i++) {
  if (subList[i].id === subNavID  && subList[i].id !== "Directorate") {
   var li = _createEl("li");
   var a = _createEl("a");
   var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(subList[i].URLNAME);

   a.href = subList[i].subURL;
   a.appendChild(aTextNode);
   ddContent.appendChild(a);  
  }
 }

 //if value is DIRECTORATE
 if (isDirectorate === "directorate") {
  //alert("I ");
  //create div and add dropdown class
  var megaDivDropDown = _createEl("div");
  megaDivDropDown.classList.add("dropdown");

  var megaBtn = _createEl("button");
  megaBtn.classList.add("dropbtn");

    megaDivDropDown.appendChild(megaBtn)
  var megaI = _createEl("i");
  megaI.classList.add("fa");
  megaI.classList.add("fa-caret-down");

  megaBtn.appendChild(megaI);

  var megaDDivContent = _createEl("div");
  megaDDivContent.classList.add("Mdropdown-content");

  var headerDiv = _createEl("div");
  headerDiv.classList.add("Mheader");

  var megaH2 = _createEl("h2");
  var h2Text = document.createTextNode("Team Sites");

  megaH2.appendChild(h2Text);
  headerDiv.appendChild(megaH2);
    megaDDivContent.appendChild(headerDiv);

  var megaDDivRow = _createEl("div");
  megaDDivRow.classList.add("Mrow");

  //Loop through categories & sub-categories items

  for (var i = 0; i < megaMenuCategory.length; i++) {
   var megaDivCol = _createEl("div");
          megaDivCol.classList.add("Mcolumn");
   var colHr = _createEl("h3");
   var colHrText = document.createTextNode(megaMenuCategory[i].category);
   colHr.appendChild(colHrText);
   megaDivCol.appendChild(colHr);
   for (var x = 0; x < categoryMenu.length; x++) {
    if (megaMenuCategory[i].category === categoryMenu[x].category) {
     var colAnchor = _createEl("a");
     colAnchor.href = categoryMenu[x].menuUrl;
     var menuColText = document.createTextNode(categoryMenu[x].menuItem);
     colAnchor.appendChild(menuColText);

     megaDivCol.appendChild(colAnchor);
          megaDDivRow.appendChild(megaDivCol);
          megaDDivContent.appendChild(megaDDivRow);
          ddDiv.appendChild(megaDDivContent);
    }
   }
   //create the other stuff
      //console.log(megaDivCol)
      console.log("megaDdivRow:")
      console.log(ddDiv);
  }
 }

 ddDiv.appendChild(ddContent);
 return ddDiv;
}

function _createEl(el) {
 return document.createElement(el);
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}




/*MEGA-MENU*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Mnavbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.Mnavbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Mdropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Mdropdown .Mdropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.Mnavbar a:hover, .Mdropdown:hover .Mdropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.Mdropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.Mdropdown-content .Mheader {
  background: #555;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.Mdropdown:hover .Mdropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.Mcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 250px;
}

.Mcolumn a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.Mcolumn a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.Mrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .Mcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the buildSubNavBar method as following.

```
function buildSubNavBar(subNavID, isDirectorate) {
    //create div and add dropdown class
    var ddDiv = _createEl("div");
    if(isDirectorate === "directorate"){
        ddDiv.classList.add("Mdropdown");
    }else{
        ddDiv.classList.add("dropdown");
    }
    //create button and add text
    var btn = _createEl("button");
    if(isDirectorate === "directorate"){
        btn.classList.add("Mdropbtn");
    }else{
        btn.classList.add("dropbtn");
    }
    var btnText = document.createTextNode(subNavID);
    //append the text to the button
    btn.appendChild(btnText);

    //create i tag and add "fa fa-caret-down" classes
    var itag = _createEl("i");
    itag.classList.add("fa");
    itag.classList.add("fa-caret-down");
    btn.appendChild(itag);
    ddDiv.appendChild(btn);

    var ddContent = _createEl("div");
    ddContent.classList.add("dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < subList.length; i++) {
        if (subList[i].id === subNavID  && subList[i].id !== "Directorate") {
            var li = _createEl("li");
            var a = _createEl("a");
            var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(subList[i].URLNAME);

            a.href = subList[i].subURL;
            a.appendChild(aTextNode);
            ddContent.appendChild(a);  
        }
    }
    if(isDirectorate === "directorate"){
        //alert("I ");
        //create div and add dropdown class
        var megaDivDropDown = _createEl("div");
        megaDivDropDown.classList.add("dropdown");

        var megaBtn = _createEl("button");
        megaBtn.classList.add("dropbtn");

        megaDivDropDown.appendChild(megaBtn)
        var megaI = _createEl("i");
        megaI.classList.add("fa");
        megaI.classList.add("fa-caret-down");

        megaBtn.appendChild(megaI);

        var megaDDivContent = _createEl("div");
        megaDDivContent.classList.add("Mdropdown-content");

        var headerDiv = _createEl("div");
        headerDiv.classList.add("Mheader");

        var megaH2 = _createEl("h2");
        var h2Text = document.createTextNode("Team Sites");

        megaH2.appendChild(h2Text);
        headerDiv.appendChild(megaH2);
        megaDDivContent.appendChild(headerDiv);

        var megaDDivRow = _createEl("div");
        megaDDivRow.classList.add("Mrow");

        //Loop through categories & sub-categories items

        for (var i = 0; i < megaMenuCategory.length; i++) {
            var megaDivCol = _createEl("div");
            megaDivCol.classList.add("Mcolumn");
            var colHr = _createEl("h3");
            var colHrText = document.createTextNode(megaMenuCategory[i].category);
            colHr.appendChild(colHrText);
            megaDivCol.appendChild(colHr);
            for (var x = 0; x < categoryMenu.length; x++) {
                if (megaMenuCategory[i].category === categoryMenu[x].category) {
                    var colAnchor = _createEl("a");
                    colAnchor.href = categoryMenu[x].menuUrl;
                    var menuColText = document.createTextNode(categoryMenu[x].menuItem);
                    colAnchor.appendChild(menuColText);

                    megaDivCol.appendChild(colAnchor);
                    megaDDivRow.appendChild(megaDivCol);
                    megaDDivContent.appendChild(megaDDivRow);
                    ddDiv.appendChild(megaDDivContent);
                }
            }
            //create the other stuff
            //console.log(megaDivCol)
            console.log("megaDdivRow:")
            console.log(ddDiv);
        }
    }
    ddDiv.appendChild(ddContent);
    return ddDiv;
}
```